# Website show Google Ads when we have no Google Ads linked to our website

Tags: plugins, security, hacked, ads

Today we noticed that one of our website has started showing random Google Ads on our website when we have not added any Google Ads to our website.

I would appreciate if someone can help in case they have faced such scenario.

I am not sure at this point if website is hacked or shared hosting server is compromised.

Any points or steps i should follow to get rid of these ads on website

Answer (score 1):

probably your website is hacked.
The first thing to do is:

1. if you still have access to your website and can log in, try to
   put it in maintenance mode (you can use any free plugin).
2. change your password and delete any unknown user.
3. if your hosting has a Malware Removal Service, use it to clean up
   your site.
4. if not, then 5
5. try to update your themes and plugins.
6. re-install WordPress (I prefer manually using FTP)
7. Re-install the plugins
8. reinstall the theme
9. Clean out your database
10. use a security tool.

To make sure your website is hacked, you can use this tool: https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

Comment: will follow your steps. as this point it seems hosting server is compromised as other website which is laravel based in also showing ads..

Comment: sitecheck.sucuri.net doesnt show anything..